# Log4J memory leaks, several processes taking up around a 1G each

Tags: java, logging, memory-leaks, log4j

Please have a look at the image below.

[image]

I am running Log4J but using the TimeAndSizeRollingFileAppender provided from http://www.simonsite.org.uk/ .

According to the site it should be a good version that is used by many companies.

What could be the cause for all these processes running independently?

I am running a WAR file, and I have this configuration:

```
# DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR < FATAL ==> DEBUG SHOWS ALL, WARN will show WARN, ERROR and FATAL

# Variable
momomo.log.pattern=%n================================%n%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss}%n%c%n%m %x%n--------------------------------%n
momomo.log.datepattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
momomo.log.maxfilesize=5MB

# Root logger option logs all to file
log4j.rootLogger=debug, error, info, console

# global info to console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=${momomo.log.pattern}
log4j.appender.console.Threshold=INFO

# global debug to file
log4j.appender.debug=uk.org.simonsite.log4j.appender.TimeAndSizeRollingAppender
log4j.appender.debug.File=/momomo/Generated/Logs/debug.log
log4j.appender.debug.DatePattern=${momomo.log.datepattern}
log4j.appender.debug.MaxFileSize=${momomo.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.debug.Append=true
log4j.appender.debug.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.debug.layout.ConversionPattern=${momomo.log.pattern}
log4j.appender.debug.Threshold=DEBUG

# global error to file
log4j.appender.error=uk.org.simonsite.log4j.appender.TimeAndSizeRollingAppender
log4j.appender.error.File=/momomo/Generated/Logs/error.log
log4j.appender.error.DatePattern=${momomo.log.datepattern}
log4j.appender.error.MaxFileSize=${momomo.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.error.Append=true
log4j.appender.error.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.error.layout.ConversionPattern=${momomo.log.pattern}
log4j.appender.error.Threshold=ERROR

# This logger just logs for the package momomo.com
log4j.logger.momomo.com=momomo, momomofatal

# momomo debug logger
log4j.appender.momomo=uk.org.simonsite.log4j.appender.TimeAndSizeRollingAppender
log4j.appender.momomo.File=/momomo/Generated/Logs/momomo.log
log4j.appender.momomo.DatePattern=${momomo.log.datepattern}
log4j.appender.momomo.MaxFileSize=${momomo.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.momomo.Append=true
log4j.appender.momomo.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.momomo.layout.ConversionPattern=${momomo.log.pattern}
log4j.appender.momomo.Threshold=DEBUG

# momomo fatal logger
log4j.appender.momomofatal=uk.org.simonsite.log4j.appender.TimeAndSizeRollingAppender
log4j.appender.momomofatal.File=/momomo/Generated/Logs/momomo.fatal.log
log4j.appender.momomofatal.DatePattern=${momomo.log.datepattern}
log4j.appender.momomofatal.MaxFileSize=${momomo.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.momomofatal.Append=true
log4j.appender.momomofatal.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.momomofatal.layout.ConversionPattern=${momomo.log.pattern}
log4j.appender.momomofatal.Threshold=FATAL
```

Yes, quite many, but there is still many more processes for logging that is declared above.

The server is running really slow now, and that isn't the case when it was just started up. It has gone slower and slower for every hour.

Comment: take heap dump with `jmap` and post it here

Comment: Use VisualVM in the JDK to attach to the process and find out where your memory is used.

Comment: Also note that you cannot immediately rely on the memory usage reported by Linux.

Comment: @JigarJoshi and \@Thorbjorn: I haven't installed VisualVM but I tried with jmap. I couldn't connect. Another problem is that these are all listed as separate processes. I am deploying a WAR to tomcat, but htop is listing them as seperate processes. I couldn't find a main process to connect to with jmap. When connecting to one of teh processes, i got: Error attaching to process: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach to the process

Comment: if you use right version of `jmap` you should be able to connect to that JVM

Comment: @JigarJoshi jmap apid resulted the above exception

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen You seem to be right. On my local machine System monitor only shows one process and 1 G of use, but htop shows several. free -m also shows very low memory free, while system monitor shows more than 8 gig free. Great tools!

Comment: are you sure you are using right version of jmap ?

Comment: @momo native threads show up like that.  This is not necessarily a bad thing.  You can only connect with a debugger to a JVM started for debugging, this is why visualvm is so good as the JVM does not need special treatment - download the JDK or from http://visualvm.java.net/ - you still need to be the same user running the JVM for the attach mechanism to work.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yes, I will install it, but I need to open ports and stuff like that, so it's a bit complicated. I am working on configuring postgresql right now, as to see if that might resolve some of these issues.